# Button click counter save number

Tags: javascript, php

I have this fiddle where when the user clicks a button the counter works:     http://jsfiddle.net/z66WF/

This is the code:

```
<button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

 var clicks = 0;
 function clickME() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
```

The problem is that I want the number to be saved, so for example:

1. user #1 clicks on the button 10 times
2. user #2 opens the site and the count is at 10, he clicks and now the counter starts 11
3. and so on with new users.

I'm trying to do this to keep track of how many times a file has been downloaded.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Yeah, store the value on the server after each click. Also, why the jQuery tag, I see none.

Comment: Send an ajax request to a script that adds each count to a database.

Comment: You would have to save the clicks number on your server, and add validation/timout to make sure someone doesn't increment it 1000000 times

Comment: as long as js is "client size" you can't save the number just un JS. You need to save it on the serveur, via ajax for exemple. On click, client start an ajax request to a php file on your server, and this php file "write" the number increased : in a text file of in a SQL database for exemple

Comment: Can you give me an example of that @PierreGranger? thank you!

Comment: An alternative would be to use HTML5 local storage.  See [this](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: @PeterVC seems good altough very complicated

Comment: Local storage will only store things on individual user's computers. It won't make information transfer between users, or back to your site.

Comment: Ah yes.  I glossed over the User1/User2 thing.  Your going to have to do a round trip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a working simple exemple, wich write the counter in a simple txt file (no sql db needed)

```
<?php

    $counterFile = 'counter.txt' ;

    // jQuery ajax request is sent here
    if ( isset($_GET['increase']) )
    {
        if ( ( $counter = @file_get_contents($counterFile) ) === false ) die('Error : file counter does not exist') ;
        file_put_contents($counterFile,++$counter) ;
        echo $counter ;
        return false ;
    }

    if ( ! $counter = @file_get_contents($counterFile) )
    {
        if ( ! $myfile = fopen($counterFile,'w') )
            die('Unable to create counter file !!') ;
        chmod($counterFile,0644);
        file_put_contents($counterFile,0) ;
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).on('click','a#download',function(){
                jQuery('div#counter').html('Loading...') ;
                var ajax = jQuery.ajax({
                    method : 'get',
                    url : '/test.php', // Link to this page
                    data : { 'increase' : '1' }
                }) ;
                ajax.done(function(data){
                    jQuery('div#counter').html(data) ;
                }) ;
                ajax.fail(function(data){
                    alert('ajax fail : url of ajax request is not reachable') ;
                }) ;
            }) ;
        </script>
    </head>
    <div id="counter"><?php echo $counter ; ?></div>
    <a href="" id="download" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">Download btn</a>
```

Comment: For security reasons, files should be chmod'ed to 644 instead of 777 and hidden away from prying eyes, in conjunction with `.htaccess`. ;)

Comment: thanks, edited to 644 ;) for htaccess i don't want to make it more complicated, it's only a readable file.

Comment: You're welcome (*de rien*) Pierre. No need to make it more complicated, I was just pointing it out. The OP can Google the rest ;)

Comment: I'm getting this error after clicking on the `download btn`: ajax fail : url of ajax request is not reachable

Comment: @codek If you're still using `url : '/test.php',` and haven't changed it to the URL that's on your server, then you will need to do something like `url : 'test.php',` if it's inside the same folder, or `url : '../test.php',` if it's one sub-folder down. Doing `/file.php` usually does not work and requires a full server path such as `/var/user/you/public_html/folder/file.php`

Comment: @codek Plus, there was a typo in the code. `chmod($counterFile,644);` which I edited/changed to `chmod($counterFile,0644);` - You may need to seperate the HTML from the PHP, which did work for me.

Comment: It works well. Thank you! Thank your the correction @Fred-ii- :)

Comment: You're welcome @codek Glad to know that it's been solved and that we are now on the same page ;) *Cheers*

Answer (score 1):

You need a DB connection to do this.

When the button is clicked, by any user, the value from let's say: "downloaded_times" will be increased with 1.

so you will need a query like:

`UPDATE table SET downloaded_times = downloaded_times + 1`

this query will be called each time someone presses the button.

If you want to display it, before a certain user wants to start a download, you simply fetch the result from DB and the echo it. You can do more, if you want that field to be constantly refreshed, the fetching and echoing part should be in a ajax called PHP function, that will refresh the div (for instance) every 30 second or so :D

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: A `WHERE` clause is needed for this to work properly if there is more than one column.

Comment: Of course, if the OP has more then 1 file then he should use a `WHERE` clause on which he should match them by file_id, but he stated: *"I'm trying to do this to keep track of how many times **a file** has been downloaded."*

Comment: It's often rare *but not unique* that a table will only have a single column and we don't know how many the OP's table contains, therefore it's always best to add the additional information. The OP stands at coming back and saying something like: *"All my columns have been reset to 1"* ;) Just dotting the i's and crossing the t's.