# Button click counter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a button click counter that on every download it increases. I want to use it without a database, this is the code:

```
<?php

    $counterFile = 'counter.txt' ;

    // jQuery ajax request is sent here
    if ( isset($_GET['increase']) )

    {
        if ( ( $counter = @file_get_contents($counterFile) ) === false ) die('Error : file counter does not exist') ;
                file_put_contents($counterFile,++$counter) ;
                echo $counter ;
                return false ;
            }

            if ( ! $counter = @file_get_contents($counterFile) )
            {
                if ( ! $myfile = fopen($counterFile,'w') )
                    die('Unable to create counter file !!') ;
                chmod($counterFile,0644);
                file_put_contents($counterFile,0) ;
            }

        ?>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             jQuery(document).on('click','a#download',function(){
                 jQuery('div#counter').html('Loading...') ;
                 var ajax = jQuery.ajax({
                     method : 'get',
                     url : '/test.php', // Link to this page
                     data : { 'increase' : '1' }
                 }) ;
                 ajax.done(function(data){
                     jQuery('div#counter').html(data) ;
                 }) ;
                 ajax.fail(function(data){
                     alert('ajax fail : url of ajax request is not reachable') ;
                 }) ;
             }) ;
         </script>
    <div id="counter"><?php echo $counter ; ?></div>
    <a href="<?php echo get_field("pdf"); ?>" id="download" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">Download btn</a>
```

The problem is that when I click on `Download btn` the pdf opens but the number dissapear, and if I reload the page it always stays at `0`.
Any idea where or what is the problem?

Comment: I remember this piece of code. You got that from http://stackoverflow.com/a/26892053/ in your other question. By using that code, you should have accepted the answer, or upvoted it. I ran that orignal code and it did not always stay at `0`, but did in fact increment in value. I actually helped in that answer to point out errors made, but no further comments were given on your part.

Comment: I did not imply that you did the code and calling it your own. You should have posted a comment under the person's answer to let that person know why it's not working, instead of posting a new question using the code.

Comment: for starters you need to stop the original link firing. `return false;` at the end of the click handler.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, my bad, sorry. Do you want me to delete this question? I should have thought of doing it that way :/

Comment: It's up to you. But you've gotten an answer and a comment about `return false;`. Leave it open, but do upvote the other answer if you haven't already and maybe letting that person know of the current problem you are having. What I think may be happening is this `url : '/test.php',` you're using a `/` in there which may be a contributing factor, as I stated in the other answer about that. If it's showing as zero, then it's not writing to the file. Using error reporting would signal an error.

Comment: To add, `url : '/test.php',` the `test.php` part of it, is the PHP for the counter. I'll take a wild guess and say that you have your PHP "and" JS all in one file, right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I have already upvoted it. As for the `url : '/test.php'` I think it's working ok now since I'm not getting this error: `download btn: ajax fail : url of ajax request is not reachable`

Comment: I have all this code in one file if that is what you mean

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You need to seperate your PHP from your JS. The PHP part that you have "is" the `url : '/test.php'` - JS is to call that file in order to call PHP and tell it to call your counter file and increase it with every click. Plus in conjunction with the answer below, have you seen it?

Comment: I got it. That was the problem!

Comment: hehehe, right on! I knew you'd get it ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64885/discussion-between-codek-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reload is down to the link being clicked (it is still a link after all, which *will* reload the page).

Either return false:

```
    jQuery(document).on('click','a#download',function(){
        ...
        return false;
    });
```

Or prevent the default action with `preventDefault()`

```
    jQuery(document).on('click','a#download',function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        ...
    });
```

You are currently using both an `onclick=` attribute and a jQuery event handler on the same button. That is not a good situation.

Best to use only jQuery for the handlers. e.g.

```
    jQuery(document).on('click','a#download',function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        window.open(this.href);
        ... The other code ...
    });
```

and remove the `onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;"` from the button.

Comment: @A. Wolff: now noted. Will that not clash with the jQuery handler which is also handling it?

Comment: I'd say no, needs some testing. But ya, better would be to set all logic inside same handler

Comment: @A. Wolff: Yes (and already added). Be interested in the effect of `return false` when both types of handlers exist. That might have blocked the jQuery handler if it fired first.

Comment: @A. Wolff: I have tried the various options and a `return false` from `onclick=` *or* a jquery handler does not stop another event *on the same button*, but `return false` *from either one* stops the default action: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wr7akn09/1/

Comment: I solved the question because I was making a silly mistake on not separating the php content on the `test.php` file. Anyway I think this improve the jQuery code part so I'm accepting it as an answer

Comment: @codek: Thank you for that. I realised there were other issues from the comments, but felt it was their job to post those answers. Happy if they do and will upvote them myself.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I did originally, as per [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891603/button-click-counter-save-number/26892053#comment42341566_26892053) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914353/button-click-counter#comment42378251_26914353). OP was using the code inside the same file instead of seperating them. Comments can be just as efficient ;)

Comment: @Fred -ii-: I get that... and if I see it posted *as an answer* I will be happy to up-vote it. :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha yeah, thanks for your help man. I pointed that in the original question ;)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It's fine and thanks for the offer. I'm just glad that this matter was resolved. *Cheers*  - I upvoted yours.